# Can you manipulate and colorize this image to show more detail than the original grayscale image?

Tags: image-processing

I've run out of ideas.  Nothing seems to bring out detail.  It's a rather interesting image ...

[image]

```
cuba = WebImage["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Kubkrise1962MRBMSite3.jpg"];
cuba1 = ImageData[ImageTake[cuba, {21, 570}, {75, 725}]][[All, All, 1]];
cuba2 = Image[cuba1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqQ6a.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried: `Colorize[cuba2]` ?

Comment: Yes, with various palettes for ColorFunction, all degrade.  The image looks like it has high entropy with no motion.

Comment: I've also tried a 10x10 popcorn kernel using 99 elements of -1 with a central element of 100.  No good.

Comment: Have you tried some of the image processing neural networks available on the [neural net repo](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/tasktype/Image-Processing)? For instance, [colourising](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-Places-Data/) and [upscaling](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Enhanced-Super-Resolution-GAN-Trained-on-DIV2K-Flickr2K-and-OST-Data/).

Comment: @Carl Lange - That is starting to look good: ```NetModel["Colorful Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition \Data"]